# In Visio, how do I get the normal looking arrows? (The line arrows not the triangle ones)

Tags: visio

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFlyweight.aspx

There is a UML diagram on that page. It has three different kinds of connections. The shared aggregation connection, the generalized connection (triangle arrow), and the other one... How do I get the other one in Visio? I can't find it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't "there". You need to specify the "Begin" and "End" shapes for your line, from the Format -> Line menu (or "More line ends" in the lines drop-down menu)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You can use this 1 legged connector

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the line formatting on arrows found in the shape libraries is buggy and tedious for me.  I think the simplest to use arrow in Visio 2010 is on the ribbon **Home > Tools > Connector**. It's easy to modify it to look like any of the arrows that Michael referenced in his link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the **Dynamic Connector** which, in the past, would appear as standard among the Basic Flowchart Shapes.

Comment: I think this is more like a comment.